# Detecting and changing URL of src in Chrome App Webview

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

Using Chrome://inspect and going to a Chrome App and then source snippets with chrome dev tools, you can use the following code to check the src attribute from a webview and redirect if it has been changed. This may occur when forexample an App is running on a public wifi that auto redirects and a set time period. I want to be able to check for that redirected URL and change it back.

```
    setInterval(function(){
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("webview")[0].getAttribute("src"); //get current domain

//pseudo code - check if x matches a domain...

        document.getElementsByTagName("webview")[0].setAttribute("src","Your URL here"); //set webview to domain
    },5000);
```

Where is the best place to put this Javascript code? And does anyone have an example.

What I have tried so far:

- inline? if so, then what is the best way to do this as an error message regarding updating the manifest file allowing "unsafe-inline". However, I have read there are security concerns regarding this.
- a js file within the app - I tried this but i was unable to find the file in the chrome dev tools to debug and it didn't work. Console.log also would not work. How do you debug JS files from within a Chrome App?
- a js file sourced from a server with a nonce? I tried to follow the instructions at http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-CSP2-20150721/#script-src-nonce-usage but couldnt get it to work. Does anyone have an example?

Also, are there any appropriate event listeners that can be used instead? I thought the webview loadRedirect event could be used. If so, where do i put this code?

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#event-loadredirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that interacts with the `<webview>` element should be running in the same document as that element. So, assuming that page is `app.html`, you would need to include a script there.

Inline code [will not work in a Chrome App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy), period. You should add a separate local `.js` file and reference it with a `<script>` element.

As for inspecting / debugging apps, you need to attach to the app window, not the background/event page. There are 2 helpful tools:

1. The page `chrome://inspect/#apps` will list all App windows and you can attach Dev Tools from there.
2. You can set a Chrome flag to enable context menu with Inspect on Chrome App windows, `chrome://flags/#debug-packed-apps`, if you expect to do it often.

Comment: thanks @Xan. With regards to referencing the script from app.html, would that be using a nonce?

Comment: That would be using a good old `<script src="app.js"></script>` - note that it has to be local to the app.

Comment: Is there an eventListener I can use rather than a setInterval?

Comment: Probably, but I don't know off-hand. Armed with DevTools, try the ones listed in webview docs. Also, see `webRequest` API - you can use it in apps for webviews